# Replacing my popup.html dynamically

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I have a popup.html opened when the user clicks the icon. The popup.html has a button. If this button is clicked i want to show another popup from a different html file after closing the current popup. Does anyone know how to do this.( I already have a listner attached to my button. All i want to know is hot to close the currently displaying popup and open a new one).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Popups are like regular tabs so `window.location.href="..."` works on them.

But you can simply popup an overlay and a fullscreen iframe inside the popup window and overlay a close button over that one.

```
 <iframe src="http://target.com" style="position:absolute; left:0; top:0; right:0; bottom:0; width:...
```

So on.

Comment: Okay. I guess i should have been a little more clear but i wanted to cut down the code and only post the relevant part. The entire popup.html not only contains a button but also other elements like text fields etc. Now loading this i frame over the current one would cause the animation to run continously in the background. Is there no way in which i can replace the popup.html dynamically to antoher file.Also if this is the only way could you please post some code as to how to close the iframe dynamically

Comment: Chrome extension popups doesn't support `window.location.href` to another web pages.

Answer (score 0):

You can use innerHTML to update popup page dynamically

```
    var event_container;
    event_container = document.getElementById('element ID');//Get location of event container
    event_container.innerHTML = event_container.innerHTML + "html string you want to add";
```